# Does sharing memory between threads makes them slower?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I'm trying to implement a naive threaded matrix multiplication, I'm creating multiple threads for each linear combination using a manually allocated result array and writing to the respective position on each thread, however my code run slower than on it's single threaded version, is it the use of memory that slows down the code?

I used heap allocation to avoid any memory copying but could it be the problem?

```
#define rows first
#define columns second 

void linear_combination(double const *arr_1,std::pair<int, int> sp_1,
                        double const *arr_2, std::pair<int, int> sp_2,
                        double *arr_3, std::pair<int, int> sp_3,
                        int base_row,int base_col){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sp_1.columns; i++){
        int idx_1 = base_row * sp_1.columns + i;
        int idx_2 = i * sp_2.columns + base_col;
        sum += arr_1[idx_1] * arr_2[idx_2];
    }
    int idx_3 = base_row * sp_3.columns + base_col;
    arr_3[idx_3] = sum;
}

auto matmul(double *m1, std::pair<int, int> sp_1, double *m2, std::pair<int, int> sp_2){
    // "sp_n" stands for shape for n-th matrix
    if (sp_1.second == sp_2.first){
        auto *m3 = (double *) malloc(sp_1.first*sp_2.second* sizeof(double));
        std::pair sp_3 = {sp_1.first, sp_2.second};

        for (int k = 0; k < sp_3.rows; k++){
            std::vector<std::thread> thread_list(sp_2.columns);
            for (int j = 0; j < sp_2.columns; j++){
                // will automatically save linear combination sum into m3

                thread_list[j] = ( std::thread(linear_combination,
                                               m1, sp_1,
                                               m2, sp_2,
                                               m3, sp_3,
                                               k, j) );
            }

            // join threads and use calculation
            std::for_each(thread_list.begin(), thread_list.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
        }

        return std::make_tuple(m3, sp_3);
    } else{
        puts("Size mismatch");
        printf("%d %d\n", sp_1.second, sp_2.first);
        double m3 = 0;
        return std::make_tuple(&m3, std::make_pair(0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a profiler?

Comment: Without looking at your code: any time 2 threads access the same cache line (usually 64 bytes), that is slow. And on NUMA systems, accessing memory from another node is slow.

Comment: How do you measure time?

Comment: How many threads are you creating? Creating and running more threads than the number of physical cores may often slow things down due to the overhead associated with context switching.

Comment: It seems that one thread is created for every iteration of the inner loop.  Now, okay, the threads created in the inner loop are waited on before continuing with the outer loop, but that means creating a total of `sp_3.rows*sp_2.columns` threads - which seems excessive.  Excessive threads will tend to thrash the system, since it needs to schedule and wait on all of them.   All of those threads accessing the same block of memory is just the tip of the iceberg.    Also, using `malloc()` in C++ is a bit .. um ... smelly.

Comment: Also, calling `thread::join` means that you're blocking the main thread so it's unable to proceed to the next iteration (the outer loop). It's hardly surprising that you don't get any performance boost from this kind of design.

Comment: Step 1: Create a _thread pool_ that has no more worker threads than your platform has CPUs to run them, and change your program to submit a new _task_ to the pool in every place where it currently creates a new thread.  Creating and destroying a thread may take more time than each of your threads spends doing the calculation.